# How to upload image data to server in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to store my image data on server in iOS using swift. i tried following code, but its not working what changes i have to do ??

Want to upload 6 images.[this is my controller view, after clicking save it want to store at server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Uc7.png)

```
func myImageUploadRequest()
{

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://easemyshop.in/upload_test/new.php");
    //let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://easemyshop.in/upload_test/new.php");

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let param = [


        "tag"  : "all",
        "count"    : "1",
        "shopname"    : "MayurShop",
        "partyName"    : "Paras",
        "cur_date"    : "14-06-2017",
        "due_date"    : "20-06-2017",
        "karagir"    : "Santra",
        "remark"    : "Urgent",
        "order_status"    : "Order Reccived"

    /*
        "firstName"  : "Mayur",
        "lastName"    : "Shinde",
        "userId"    : "101"

        */
    ]

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((imageView?.image!)!, 1)

    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data

    myActivityIndicator.isHidden = false
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
    {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("******** error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("\n\n******* response *******\n\n")
        print("\(response!)")
    print("\n\n**************************\n\n")

        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        print("\n\n****** response data *******\n\n")
        print("\(responseString!)")
        print("\n\n**************************\n\n")

        do
        {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

            print("\n\n*************\n\n")
            print(json!)
            print("\n\n*************\n\n")

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.myActivityIndicator.isHidden = true
                //self.imageView?.image = nil;
            });

        }
        catch
        {
            print("\n\n*************ERROR******** => \(error)\n\n")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}


func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")



    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}



func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? also anything in the server logs?

Comment: @geminiCoder its doen's show any error in XCode. But still not uploaded on server. On server it shows - This directory is empty. Means data is not uploaded !!!

Comment: So my first question would be is stuff actually being sent to the server, i.e in the server logs is it showing a POST? On Linux the log is normally in /var/log/ look for apache or httpd and there should be a access log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func webServiceImageUploadForMyProfile(image:UIImage,url:String,method:HTTPMethod,parameters : [String:AnyObject]?,completionHandler:@escaping (JSON?,String)->Void) {

    let url = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: nil)
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
        if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "Profile.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
        }, with: url, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, , ):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if(response.result.isSuccess){
                        if let data = response.result.value{
                            let json = JSON(data)
                            print(json)
                            completionHandler(json,String())
                            return
                        }
                    }else {
                        completionHandler(nil,(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)!)
                    }
                    }

            case .failure( _):

                break
            }
    })
}
```

please try ...

Answer (score 3):

Please give a try with below code to upload the image on your server, also replace **fileName** variable value with one in which you want to send the image file to your server.

```
func uploadImage(urlString:String,headers:[String:String]?,params:[String:String]?,image:UIImage?){
    let boundary: String = "------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy"
    let contentType: String = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.url = URL(string: urlString)
    if let tHeaders = headers {
        for (key, value) in tHeaders {
            request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
    }
    request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let body = NSMutableData()
    if let parameters = params {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        }
    }
    //which field you have to sent image on server
    let fileName: String = "file"
    if image != nil {
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fileName)\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type:image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    request.httpBody = body as Data
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No response from server")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

at your PHP server, you can get your file name like this

```
<?php
   echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
?>
```

Comment: In this method, where you are passing "urlString:String", ======>     let body = NSMutableData()
        if let parameters = params {
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            }
        }